# Multiple descendant children selector with css

Tags: css, css-selectors

Check this code below:

```css
.aaa :not(.bbb) .ccc {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="aaa">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="bbb">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="ccc">AQUI</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to match all `.ccc` element that are children of `.aaa` but are not children of `.bbb`. It means that the code above should NOT make the AQUI word be RED, but it gets RED anyway. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `not(.bbb)` will match any div without the class `.bbb` and you have a lot of them between `.aaa` and `.ccc` that why the text is red. To do what you want you need to consider two selectors

```css
.aaa .ccc {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FF0000;
}
/*we reset the style if children of .bbb*/
.bbb .ccc {
  color: initial;
  font-size:initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="aaa">

  <div>

    <div>

      <div class="bbb">

        <div>

          <div>

            <div class="ccc">AQUI</div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I liked very much your solution, worked perfectly! It fitted like a glove to my case, thanks my friend.

Answer (score 4):

There are actually elements which are not `.bbb` - the two divs before and after `.bbb` in this case. For this to work, you'll need to be more specific. You can add another class (`zzz` in the example), and if this class is not combined with `.bbb` the rule will be applied.

```css
.aaa .zzz:not(.bbb) .ccc {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="aaa">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="zzz bbb">
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="ccc">AQUI</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I liked a lot your idea. But why `.aaa div:not(.bbb) .ccc` does not work? I tried being more specific as you said but it looks like this is not enough. I have no access to HTML code, only the CSS file.

Comment: Because there are other divs which don't have `.bbb` in the way.

Comment: I am not sure if this will work in all the cases, because if you remove the div with the class `zzz bbb` you will not select the `ccc` ... your selector is like `.aaa .randomClass .ccc`, you introduced a random selector between `aaa` and `ccc` making the selection impossible

Comment: @Ori Drori thanks a lot, your solution is indeed very nice but it demands changing HTML code which is not possible in my case. But I liked a lot your solution, thanks! Temani Afif you are right :)

Answer (score 1):

You have overlooked that the `.ccc` *is* a child of components that match `:not(.bbb)`:

```
<div class="aaa">
  <div class="ccc"></div>
  <div class="bbb">
    <div> // <-- :not(.bbb)
      <div class="ccc"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You need to write two rules:

```
.aaa .ccc {
  color: blue;
}

.aaa .bbb .ccc {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention, your solution also works but the  Temani Afif  resets the css styles (which I was not aware of the initial) and worked better. But thanks a lot!