# Select elements which are not a child of something with a particular attribute property

Tags: css, css-selectors

Essentially I want all "a" elements to be red, except in situation where they are a descendant child of an element with an attribute property of "data-foo".

This html:

```
<div data-foo="whatever">
  <div>
    ... more descendants 
       <a href="#">I should be default color</a>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#">I should be red</a>
```

With this CSS:

```
:not([data-foo]) a {
  color: red;
}
```

In this example still selects both "a" elements. I also tried the following:

```
div:not([data-foo]) a
*:not([data-foo]) a
div:not([data-foo]) a
*:not(div[data-foo]) a
```

But I'm either getting nothing selected or all selected. Is this a possible selection to make?

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/52481037/8620333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy - first set the more general rule (all anchors are red), and then make a specific exception (except for the ones that have an ancestor with the 'data-foo' attribute):

```
a { color:red; }
[data-foo] a { color:inherit; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add two rules, one for all `A` and the other for `[data-foo] > a` with `color: unset;` (or the specific color you want):

```css
A {
    color: red;
}

[data-foo]  A {
    color: inherited; 
}
```

```html
<div data-foo="whatever">
  <a href="#">I should be default color</a>
</div>

<a href="#">I should be red</a>
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this because I need to fall back to inherited styles (it might not be blue). Also, the 'a' isn't always a direct descendant of that particular attributed div (it could be multiple divs deep).

Comment: Tough competition hehe.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
:not([data-foo]) > a {
  color: red;
}
```

'Greater than' > selects immediate children

Comment: This is correct. Might be worth mentioning that the OP's code didn't work because the universal selector (the space character between `:not([data-foo])` and `a`) makes the rule as written apply to `a` tags which have *any ancestor* which does not have the `data-foo` attribute.

Comment: Sorry, I should probably specify a little further. I want the :not to select anywhere up the lineage not just a direct child.

Comment: So: <div data-foo><div><div><a> would still apply

Comment: @nvioli Yes the space was intentional, any ancestor is what I'm looking for